# Uploading a new version of a rejected app to the App Store

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I uploaded an app last week to the store, but it was rejected in review.

Now that I need to upload it again, can I upload a completely new version?

What are the steps to making a new version and uploading it to the app store?

Comment: Just make changes to your existing app and re upload it.

Comment: So i open up my xcode project, do the changes. Then do the same process for uploading a new app? That's all...?

Comment: What do you mean by "version" here?

Comment: I've uploaded the initial app version 1.0 Now i want to change the version to 1.1 with minor changes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to redo all steps that was done for publishing a new app. Good luck!

Comment: Do i need to do some new steps? I thought i needed to change the version number in xcode somewhere... Isnt that true ?

Comment: The version number needs to be changed only for app updates. Since the app is not yet published you can use version 1.0 itself.

Answer (score 0):

Because your version 1.0 is rejected, so in apple store, it does not has any app contents related to version 1.0 now. So what you need to do is just make your app's version to be 1.0 again and change the parts of app followed by the reason why you have been rejected. Achieve the app and upload it again (as you did it before) as 1.0 version.

Comment: It's so dumb... All i had to change is the title of the app and they make me re-upload the whole thing which is pretty complicated... Anyway thanks!

Comment: 17yrsDev, Yep...That is true...they will review again and you need to wait nearly 2 weeks. (I have the same experiences too...painful waiting)..